# What is help command in grub rescue mode

Tags: grub2, grubrescue, execute-command

I tried `?`, `man` and `help` but these commands did not give me any help. I am looking for a command to show help in `grub rescue` mode

Comment: I don't think there is one, but I'm curious to know if there is.

Comment: `grub rescue` shell only supports `insmod`, `ls` ,`set`  and `unset` commands

Comment: @Ron Couldn't that slightly expanded (since there's really not much more to say about it) be a good answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Booting to `grub rescue` means that GRUB failed to load the ‘normal’ module (which is responsible for reading `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`, running the menu, etc.) for some reason.

The rescue shell as such is very primitive and do not offer most of the normal filesystem commands, tab completion (but offers after you load the modules), history, etc. Instead it only supports `insmod`, `ls` ,`set` and `unset` commands.

One of the most common reasons you end up in `grub resuce` is that the `prefix` environment variable is wrong (perhaps it refers to the wrong device, or perhaps the path to `/boot/grub` was not correctly made relative to the device). If this is the problem, you can correct it by:

```
# Inspect the current prefix (and other preset variables):
set
# Find out which devices are available:
ls
# Set to the correct value, which might be something like this:
set prefix=(hd0,1)/grub
set root=(hd0,1)
insmod normal
normal
```

Refer [this](https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/776643-how-to-rescue-a-non-booting-grub-2-on-linux/) excellent post and of course the grub2 [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/index.html#Top) to know more.

Comment: Nice answer, +1